# How is tumblr's X-Tumblr-Content-Rating defined?

Tags: tumblr, rating-system

tumblr offers up an X-Tumblr-Content-Rating header from its webpages.  How is that defined precisely?  Is it hand-labeled by Tumblr?  Do its users apply it?

```
$ curl -I puppies.tumblr.com 2>&1 | grep Content-Rating
$ curl -I evawomans.tumblr.com 2>&1 | grep Content-Rating
X-Tumblr-Content-Rating: nsfw
$ curl -I porn.tumblr.com 2>&1 | grep Content-Rating
X-Tumblr-Content-Rating: adult
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blog owners can flag their blogs as "NSFW" or as "adult" (at `tumblr.com/blog/YOURBLOG/settings`):

> **Flag as NSFW**
> NSFW blogs may contain occasional nudity or mature/adult oriented content.
>
> **Flag as adult**
> Adult blogs contain substantial nudity or mature/adult oriented content.

See Tumblr’s documentation about it: http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/nsfw

The Tumblr team might flag blogs, too:

> If you're not sure if you should flag your blog you can leave it unflagged, but keep in mind that we might flag it later if we see a lot of mature/adult-oriented content.

---

Before Yahoo acquired Tumblr, blog owners could only flag their blogs as "NSFW" (and there was no documentation about it).

Comment: Great info. Are you fairly sure that the flagging of the blog is what comes through as X-Tumblr-Content-Rating? That is a plausible claim.

Comment: @dfrankow: Yes, as soon as you save the setting, the header is updated. If you don’t flag your blog, there is no `X-Tumblr-Content-Rating` header present. -- It seems that you can’t change the flag as soon as you saved it (you can’t even switch from "NSFW" to "adult").

Comment: Note: Tumblr changed some settings, so my answer doesn’t apply anymore in full. See [my answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/59248/24166) on [webapps.se].